# Combining an element from a variable to connect to another variable

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to make Solitare for a school project and have run into an issue of trying to make a counter for the suit piles. The way I am currently trying to do this is by defining a global variable like is shown below:

```
var Hpilecount = "01";
var Dpilecount = "01";
var Spilecount = "01";
var Cpilecount = "01";
```

and I am trying to refer to this variable as is shown below:

```
function movecard(id) {
    console.log(id[0]+pilecount);
}
```

How can I combine the element of the varible id and something to refer to these variables.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If they are in the global scope, then you can use `window` with bracket notation to access them (as all golbal variables are properties in the global object `window`):

```js
var Hpilecount = "01";
var Dpilecount = "01";
var Spilecount = "01";
var Cpilecount = "01";

var id = "C";
var value = window[id + "pilecount"];

console.log(value);
```

If not then just group them into an object and use that oject to access the value:

```js
var pack = {
  Hpilecount: "01",
  Dpilecount: "01",
  Spilecount: "01",
  Cpilecount: "01"
}

var id = "C";
var value = pack[id + "pilecount"]; // use pack instead of window

console.log(value);
```

Comment: How would I use the window method to update the original variables such that when i add the appropriate card to the pile that it goes to 02 from 01?

Comment: That would be easy as: `window[id + "pilecount"] = "02";`.

Comment: Whoops, don't know why I didn't think of that. Cheers